# Varios servicios corriendo en docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy trabajando en un dockerfile para una aplicación que necesita de varios servicios (Redis, MongoDB, y otros 4 específicos de la aplicación).

Cuando intento generar el contenedor con:

```
docker build .
```

Todo parece ir bien, pero cuando entro en el contenedor con:

```
docker run -it <idcontenedor>
```

MongoDB y Redis están parados

Ejecuto lo siguiente en el Dockerfile para inicializarlos.

```
USER root
CMD service redis-server start
CMD service mongodb start
```

Alguien podría indicarme como debo lanzarlo para que se queden funcionando? Sin ellos funcionando desde el inicio, el script que lanzo luego para los otros 4 servicios, no pueden arrancar.

He leido también que quizás con docker-composer es mejor hacer esto, de manera que se aislan los servicios en imagenes individuales y docker-composer los levanta y conviven juntos, que me recomendais?

Answer (score 0):

el commando run creo que le faltan parametros intenta

`docker start -d -p 8080:80 --name NOMBRE_DEL_CONTAINER NOMBRE_DE_LA_IMAGEN`

asi dejaria el contenedor corriendo sobre un puerto, que son los que estan despues de -p

el docker compose necesitas armar el archivo que es algo asi

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

solo usas el siguiente comando `docker-compose up`
le puedes añadir al compose tu misma aplicación

```
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que tus servicios estén corriendo, pero al momento de poner `docker run -it <id>` se sobreescriba el entrypoint y no se ejecuten las instrucciones que diste en el `CMD`.

Trata de que, como anteriormente lo hacías, correr tu contenedor pero con el parámetro `-d` y no `-i` y después de que te asegures que esté corriendo con un `docker ps` ahora si envía al contenedor `docker exec -it <tag-del-contenedor> ps -fea` para ver qué servicios están corriendo dentro.

Si esto no te funciona, trata de hacer lo siguiente.

Para correr tanto `mongo` como `redis` en un contenedor, utilicé este Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install mongodb redis-server -y \
    && mkdir -p /data/db/

COPY script.sh /root/script.sh
CMD [ "/root/script.sh" ]
```

Y en mi archivo 'script.sh' sólamente puse un.

```
#!/bin/bash

redis-server &
mongod
```

Donde la última instrucción la puse sin el `&` para mantener corriendo el contenedor y que no se pare de inmediato.

Después creo la imagen con `docker build . -t mongo`

Después de construir el la imagen, corro el contenedor de la forma

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:2001:27017 -p 127.0.0.1:2002:6379 --name mongo -t mongo
```

mapeando los puertos 27017 y 6379 del contenedor a los puertos 2001 y 2002 respectivamente del host en la ip 127.0.0.1, tu puedes mapearlos a cualquier ip que tengas disponible o a todas las disponibles, como con la pseudo ip 0.0.0.0.

Ya después puedes verificar que tienes corriendo esos servicios con

```
mongo --port 2001
```

y con

```
redis-cli -p 2002
```